# Codeigniter PJAX redirect after successful login

Tags: php, codeigniter, pjax

So I can log in and the page view updates however the URL is not updating. What do I need to do to get the URL to match the page that loads after successful login?

```
if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember)) {
            //if the login is successful
            $this->output->set_header('X-PJAX-URL: ' . base_url('u/' . $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->username));
            $this->output->set_header('Location: ' . base_url('u/' . $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->username), false);
}
```

this should update the URL to localhost/u/username and display the users profile. It displays the users profile but does not update the URL to localhost/u/username